# Best Practice for Laravel Asynchronous Requests

Tags: php, laravel, curl, asynchronous, laravel-5

I have a Laravel application. The application loading perfectly fine, when I only make 3-10 API per page in my controller.
Now, I start to see the latency when I start making `200 API` requests per page in my controller.

Since Laravel is MVC.

All the code in the controller need to be fully executed and finished, and then it will send all the data/variables to the view.
But that is leading to a lot of latency.

I’m thinking to perform that APIs call asynchronously, but I am not sure which one is the best move,

I did a quick search, I found :

- PHP cURL Async: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php
- Laravel Async: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues
- PHP Promise: https://github.com/reactphp/promise

Any directions/suggestions on this will mean a lot to me, and others that faced this issue.

Comment: IMO you are trying to solve it in a wrong way. Just use a background task and let the client ask for updates on the progress instead. Also depending on the lifetime of the results cache it instead of making api calls.

Comment: Also your second link has nothing to do with async

Comment: I am looking into Laravel queue right now, but I am not sure if that is the best way to solve this.

Comment: Can you not combine some of the requests into single larger requests?  200 api calls to deliver a single page seems like way too many, but that depends on what you're doing.

Comment: Why can't you move these api calls out of the method that block from rendering the view and use something like axios to asynchronously fetch that data and render what you need? If you are using vuejs or any other front end framework you should be able to remove those blocking api calls and leverage js to fetch and render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explore using [Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#connections-vs-queues) for this. Offload any calls to the queue, await for response.

I would recommend against 200 requests per page, it seems excessive. Perhaps start with trying to get that down before rearchitecting.